# Python concurrent futures multiprocessing Pool does not scale with the number of processors

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have written a simple function to demonstrate this behavior which iteratively creates a list and I pass that function to the `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`. The actual function isn't important as this seems to happen for a wide variety of functions I've tested.  As I increase the number of processors it takes longer to run the underlying function.  At only 10 processors the total execution time per processor increases by 2.5 times! For this function it continues to increase at a rate of about 15% per processor up to the capacity limits of my machine.  I have a Windows machine with 48 processors and my total CPU and memory usage doesn't exceed 25% for this test. I have nothing else running. Is there some blocking lurking somewhere?

```
from datetime import datetime
import concurrent.futures

def process(num_jobs=1,**kwargs) :

    from functools import partial
   
    iterobj = range(num_jobs)
    args = []
    func = globals()['test_multi']

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_jobs) as ex:
        ## using map
        result = ex.map(partial(func,*args,**kwargs),iterobj)

    return result

def test_multi(*args,**kwargs):

    starttime = datetime.utcnow()
    iternum = args[-1]
    test = []
    for i in range(200000):
        test = test + [i]
    
    return iternum, (datetime.utcnow()-starttime)


if __name__ == '__main__' :

    max_processors = 10
    
    for i in range(max_processors):      
        starttime = datetime.utcnow()
        result = process(i+1)
        finishtime = datetime.utcnow()-starttime
        if i == 0:
            chng = 0
            total = 0
            firsttime = finishtime
        else:
            chng = finishtime/lasttime*100 - 100
            total = finishtime/firsttime*100 - 100
        lasttime = finishtime
        print(f'Multi took {finishtime} for {i+1} processes changed by {round(chng,2)}%, total change {round(total,2)}%')
```

This gives the following results on my machine:

```
Multi took 0:00:52.433927 for 1 processes changed by 0%, total change 0%
Multi took 0:00:52.597822 for 2 processes changed by 0.31%, total change 0.31%
Multi took 0:01:13.158140 for 3 processes changed by 39.09%, total change 39.52%
Multi took 0:01:26.666043 for 4 processes changed by 18.46%, total change 65.29%
Multi took 0:01:43.412213 for 5 processes changed by 19.32%, total change 97.22%
Multi took 0:01:41.687714 for 6 processes changed by -1.67%, total change 93.93%
Multi took 0:01:38.316035 for 7 processes changed by -3.32%, total change 87.5%
Multi took 0:01:51.106467 for 8 processes changed by 13.01%, total change 111.9%
Multi took 0:02:15.046646 for 9 processes changed by 21.55%, total change 157.56%
Multi took 0:02:13.467514 for 10 processes changed by -1.17%, total change 154.54%
```

The increases are not linear and vary from test to test but always end up significantly increasing the time to run the function. Given the ample free resources on this machine and very simple function I would have expected the total time to remain fairly constant or perhaps slightly increase with the spawning of new processes, not to increase dramatically from pure calculation.

Comment: This is a big topic ... for simplicity, there are many aspects that would affect the performance VERY MUCH.  SOME of the important aspects, hardware, cache, memory coble, and serial code part, besides bug-in code.  However, keep in mind, there is a theoretical parallel speedup up-bound there limits the performance.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there are many things going on and potentially competing for resources but for this simple creation of a list, which is all in memory I believe, I would not expect that going from one processor to two processors increases the time it takes each processor to run the function by 15% in this example.   If I start other apps on the machine which run on other processors and then just run this function on one processor, it is NOT slower.  Shouldn't it be slowed by other apps just like it is slowed when two are running inside python multiprocessing?  This seems to be specific to Pool.

Answer (score 1):

yes there is, and it's called **MEMORY BANDWIDTH**.

while the memory controller is good at pipelining read/write instructions to improve throughput for parallel programs, if too many applications are reading/writing to your RAM sticks then you are going to see a slowdown because the RAM pipeline is being bombarded from all applications at the same time.

other applications running at the same time may not be using the RAM as heavily because each core has cache (L1,L2 and a shared L3) to keep applications running without contesting on the RAM bandwidth, so only applications that do heavy memory operations will be contesting on the RAM bandwidth, and your application is clearly contesting with itself on the RAM bandwidth.

this is one of the hard limits on parallel programs, and the solution is obviously to make a more "Cache friendly" application that reaches out for your RAM less often.

"Cache friendly applications" are more easily written in C/C++ than python, but they are totally doable in python as computers have a few MBs of cache which can fit an entire application in a lot of cases.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, this makes sense to me since in the example I used above the list grows in size. However, if I pre-allocate the memory by using Numpy e.g. test = np.empty(200000,dtype=np.int) and then fill in the pre-allocated array, this also slows down.  Does "cache friendly" mean more than pre-allocating all arrays?

Comment: @WGee It has to do with any memory read or write, not just reserving memory, basically anything that reads/writes to the RAM will eventually hit this bottleneck, you have to use the cache more often instead of the ram, but "cache friendly programs" is an advanced topic, and you might want to check "data oriented design"

Comment: If you just want the takeaway then, you are being slowed down by your RAM, get a faster one, if you want the long version then you need months to study data oriented design and remove that overhead by rewriting your code to be cache friendly

Comment: understood but it is disappointing.  I'm sure I could spend years learning C++ and better memory management but I thought the whole point of Python was to be able to code simply and not have to worry about that sort of thing.   This is example app is one line, list = list + [x].  That's not a line of code I'd expect I'd need to take months to learn how to code properly.

Comment: @WGee your multiprocessing python code is faster than the non-multiprocessing code for the same data size, but squeezing the last drop of performance out of your application isn't what python is good at, not without enough experience, if python was that good then we wouldn't need C/C++ anymore, but that's reality, if a language is perfect then other languages wouldn't exist, but you can appreciate how python makes it a lot easier to scale the work across multiple cores or devices compared to C++ complexity, for a small overhead depending on code, ps: `list = list + [x]` is bad code, use append

Comment: The whole point of using list = list + [x] was to purposely write something that will obviously be slow to demonstrate the behavior.   Unfortunately, list.append(x) is apparently bad code as well, it slows down exactly the same way as you add processors even though the time per process will obviously be faster.